# how to insert one or more link in comma-separated in database?

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I want to insert "http//" link with comma-separated in database 
in this form are:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask,
```

That is my insert query

```
$url = array($_REQUEST[url_name]);
$arr = implode(',', $url);
mysql_query("insert into url(url_name)values('$arr')");
```

How is it possible with an `http` link save in database with comma-separated?

Comment: that isn't a very good idea

Comment: You are opening yourself to SQL injections and bad table design. Update your driver, use parameterized queries, and only store one value per row. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Using comma-separated lists in a database column creates a myriad of problems; sensible normalization of your database eliminates those problems

Comment: Don't use the deprecated and insecure `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not good practice to store value**.

Use [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php):

$a = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"

```
base64_encode($a);
```

To get your original Value : [base64_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)

```
base64_decode($a);
```